# Oracle SQL - Comparing duplicate values

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, comparison

I have a table with the field **RANGE** that has the values in the following way:

```
102453
104953-256454
```

The values can be single 6 digit number or two 6 digit numbers separated by a dash.

User enters the a value (either a 6 digit number or two 6 digit number separated by a dash), and the value has to be compared with the existing values in the database.

- if the value entered is 6 digit number, then it should be compared with all the single 6 digit values in the database, and also with the separate 6 digit values stored as 2 digit values separated by a (-)
- if the value entered is two 6 digit numbers, then it should be parsed, and each value has to be compared by each value in the database.

How do I go about it ?

Comment: Use two separate columns instead. (If you can't change the table, you can use a view, derived table or a cte.)

Comment: That's the client design unfortunately.

Comment: You can use REGEXP_SUBSTR(s, '[^-]+', 1, 1)  and REGEXP_SUBSTR(s, '[^-]+', 1, 2)  to get both the 6 digit values from the input and use them with LIKE operator.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is some kind of ID field (I hope).

```
with Dumbassery as
(
select id, 'Single' as NumType, substr(MyField,1,6) as Num1, '' as Num2
from MyTable
where length(MyField) = 6
union
select id, 'Range' as NumType, substr(MyField,1,6) as Num1, substr(MyField,8,6) as Num2
from MyTable
where length(MyField) = 13
)

, Filter1 as
(
select id,
       case
           when exists (select 1 from Dumbassery D2 where D1.Num1 between D2.Num1 and D2.Num2 and D2.NumType = 'Range') then 'Exists'
           when exists (select 1 from Dumbassery D2 where D2.NumType = 'Single' and D1.Num1 = D2.Num1) then 'Exists'
           else 'New'
       end as NumExist
from Dumbassery D1
where D1.NumType = 'Single'

union

select id,
       case
           when exists (select 1 from Dumbassery D2 where D1.Num1 between D2.Num1 and D2.Num2 and D2.NumType = 'Range') then 'Exists'
           when exists (select 1 from Dumbassery D2 where D1.Num2 between D2.Num1 and D2.Num2 and D2.NumType = 'Range') then 'Exists'
           when exists (select 1 from Dumbassery D2 where D2.Num2 between D1.Num1 and D1.Num2 and D2.NumType = 'Single') then 'Exists'
           else 'New'
       end as NumExist
from Dumbassery D1
where D1.NumType = 'Range'
)

select distinct *
from Filter1
where NumExist = 'New'
```

Answer (score 0):

As you field named range I think you need to find intersections with new range. I add table **test_val** to check some variations of new_range.

```
 WITH
 table_ranges AS /*is table with ranges*/
 (select '123212' as range from dual union all
  select '123214-223214' as range from dual union all 
  select '123900-987121' as range from dual )
 ,test_val as /*is table with test values*/
 (select '123212' as test_range from dual union all 
  select '123213' as test_range from dual union all 
  select '123215' as test_range from dual union all 
  select '123213-123290' as test_range from dual union all 
  select '124000-125000' as test_range from dual union all 
  select '987000-987124' as test_range from dual union all 
  select '987122-987124' as test_range from dual ) 
  select CAse WHEN EXISTS (select null
                             from table_ranges 
                        where substr(t.test_range,  1,6) between substr(range, 1,6) and substr(range, -6,6) 
                           or substr(t.test_range, -6,6) between substr(range, 1,6) and substr(range, -6,6) ) 
              THEN 'already exists' 
              ELSE'intersection not found' 
            END AS test_status 
   FROM test_val t
```